# How to name form input control as sub array in post data

Tags: php

It can be treated an array row as a representation of database table row but I'm not able to give naming structure of form input control.

```
<table>
    <tr>        
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[][id]"  value="2135"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[][first_name]" value="John" /></td>            
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[][last_name]" value="Doe"/></td>         
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="empl[][id]"  value="3245"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[][first_name]" value="Sally" /></td>            
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[][last_name]" value="Smith"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Php var_dump result is like a full array for all the controls and its difficult to read and unstructured.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 2135 ) [1] => Array ( [first_name] => John ) [2] => Array ( [last_name] => Doe ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 3245 ) [4] => Array ( [first_name] => Sally ) [5] => Array ( [last_name] => Smith ) )
```

Whereas, ideally the result I wanted should be in a structure like this:

```
array(
    array(
        'id' => 2135,
        'first_name' => 'John',
        'last_name' => 'Doe',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 3245,
        'first_name' => 'Sally',
        'last_name' => 'Smith',
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name your input fields with **explicit** indexes:

```
<table>
    <tr>        
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>First Name</td>
        <td>Last Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][id]"  value="2135"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][first_name]" value="John" /></td>            
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[0][last_name]" value="Doe"/></td>         
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[1][id]"  value="3245"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[1][first_name]" value="Sally" /></td>            
        <td><input type="text" name="empl[1][last_name]" value="Smith"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this case you'll get the required structure.